# JQuery Template - Calls ${$item.function()} more than is specified in the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, jquery-templates

Jquery-tmpl seems to call functions you attach to `item` multiple times.

**JSfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abQwc/2/

The console.log's show rowCount got called 4 times for each item rendered by the template.

Template:

```
<h1 class="${$item.rowCount() % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"}">${Name} - ${Payload}</h1
```

Data:

```
    data = [
        { Name: "1", Payload: "Data1" },
        { Name: "2", Payload: "Data2" },
        { Name: "3", Payload: "Data3" } 
    ]
```

Script:

```
    $(function() {$( "#template" )
        .tmpl(data, {
            rowCount: function(){
                var rowCount = 0;
                return function(){
                    console.log(this.data.Payload);
                    return ++rowCount;
                }
            }()
        })
        .appendTo( "body" )})
```

Why?  I've already figured out how to get around it, but it reeks of witchcraft.

Comment: Is `return (++rowCount)%2 ? 'even':'odd';` in the closure your witchcraft?

Comment: No, `${($item.rowCount() / 4) % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'}` in the template is the demonry

Comment: This might be worth a try then: http://jsfiddle.net/abQwc/3/

Comment: That does work.  Why would simply ++rowCount cause it to be called 4 times though?  Also, you referenced the rowCount function but didn't execute it (`item.rowCount()` vs `item.rowCount`), how is the function executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced:

```
${$item.rowCount() % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"}
...
return function(){
    console.log(this.data.Payload);
    return ++counter;
}
```

with

```
${$item.rowCount()}
....
return function() {
    console.log(this.data.Payload);
    return (++counter) % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}
```

and was able to get it to work. However, the Options parameter was still getting executed 4 times for each item. I believe calculations like that in tmpl are still iffy at best.